# Как получить новую версию Oracle.ManagedDataAccess?

Tags: oracle, odac

На сайте oracle выложена запись о новой версии 21.3

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/new-dotnet-features.html

Поискал по сайту - все ссылки ведут на  nuget репозиторий

https://www.nuget.org/packages/oracle.manageddataaccess/

на котором последняя версия 19.11

Не могу понять, как получить последнюю версию, что для этого нужно сделать, ищу уже не первый день.

Comment: Заметки о нововведениях с указанием версии вовсе не значат, что они уже доступны публично для скачивания.

Comment: Вроде уже выложили: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/21.3.0

Comment: @defaultlocale спасибо!